# path relative to document root in PHP

Tags: php, relative-path, fopen

Hi im using XAMPP to host a site locally.

The DocumentRoot is as follows: `DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs"`
The siteDir is in the htdocs folder and has a php folder underneath is.

I am trying to use php `fopen` with a file relative to the site root `(D:/xampp/htdocs/site)` as follows: `$log = fopen("/log.log", "a")` however this is creating the file log.log in `D:/log.log`

Any ideas why this is creating in D:/ ( I would have expected / to be web root relative)

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have used an **absolute path** in your code, so PHP acts right.

write a simple code and take a look at **$_SERVER** variable:

```
<?php
echo '<xmp>';
print_r($_SERVER);
echo '</xmp>';
?>
```

you'll find appropriate key to use in your code. before the `log.log`

in my case that would be like this:

```
<?php

$sRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

$fp = fopen($sRoot . '/log.log', 'w');

?>
```

Answer (score 6):

The `/` indicates you're starting from filesystem root. If you want to do things relative to document root you can do (it's just another method to do this)

```
chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
$fp = fopen('log.log', 'w');
```

With this solution the "working directory" will remain the document root.